# Apache Virtual Host configuration issue

Tags: apache

my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName education.com
    ServerAlias www.education.com
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/Education"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/education.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/education.com-access_log" common
        <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/Education">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow, deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my hosts file is

```
127.0.0.1   education.com
127.0.0.1   www.education.com
```

I'm on a mac, not sure what am I doing wrong here. (if i remove

```
<VirtualHost
```

section localhost works fine, otherwise none of them works)

log says

```
[Sat May 03 15:17:09 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /usr/\xe2\x80\x9c, referer: http://education.com/
[Sat May 03 15:17:46 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /usr/\xe2\x80\x9c
```

Comment: Well, maybe nothing is wrong? Or do you actually have a problem with that setup?

Comment: yes, education.com is not accessible

Comment: Ah, you should say so in your question, don't you agree?

Comment: Any errors in your log files when you restart the http server as required?

Comment: updated the question with the log

Comment: But you still have artefacts, so that parts of your text is not readable. _Fix that_. ("(if i remove...")

Comment: You said "is not accessible"... could it be that you get a "permission denied" error? I cannot believe you have a problem to _access_ the server...

Comment: updated. There was a time when it said permission denied, but now it's totally inaccessible.

Comment: That does not help much, we need the current situation and the current log entries. If it _really_ is not accessible, then either the name resolution fails or the http server is not running or a firewall blocks access or, in _very_ rare cases an internal error can lead to that error (but then you'd have an entry in the log files). Please take care that you are not dealing with a caching issue: make a _deep reload_ in your browser or clear its content cache.

Comment: that's it, same log was repeated throughout the file

Comment: access log said 127.0.0.1 - - [03/May/2014:15:18:11 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202

Comment: Sorry, that does not match. On the one hand you say "but now it's totally inaccessible", on the other hand you say you _do_ have 403 entries in the log file. It is either/or. Are you sure those entries match the _current_ requests? Monitor the log files with the `tail -f` utility and repeat the requests.

Comment: I removed VirtualHost, restarted server, my localhost starts to work, something wrong with VirtualHost there. and education.com points to same as localhost (because of hosts file)

Comment: Any `DENY` directives in the central config file (`httpd.conf`) maybe …?

Comment: my httpd.conf https://www.dropbox.com/s/1h4ad1e4zl0c6id/httpd.conf

Comment: solved using apachectl configtest, there were some syntax errors, space issue between allow,deny

Answer (score 0):

define your directory like this:

```
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/Education">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow, deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: solved using apachectl configtest, there were some syntax errors, space issue between allow,deny – can you please explain why space between allow, deny is an error?